# AndEngine - Scene variables won't reset after changing the scene

Tags: java, android, variables, andengine, scene

Here is the scenario:

i have following Scenes:

1. SplashScene
2. LoadingScene
3. GameModeScene
4. PlayModeScene
5. GameScene

I have a SceneController class which manages navigation between scenes.
In SceneController i have instances to all the Scenes.

I'm initializing all the scene instances and doing loading of all scene resources in LoadingScene.

When i change scene from GameModeScene to PlayModeScene - Works Perfectly fine.
But, When i try to change the scene again to GameModeScene the boolean and other variables initialized during 1st run of GameModeScene remains as it is and won't reset.

**Note** : Variables are private to each class and are non-static

I tried pGameModeSceneto.reset(); but it won't work.
Anyy suggestions?

Here is how i'm initializing scene insatnces

---

**SceneController.loadSceneResources()**

```
public void loadSceneResources(SceneType mType){
        switch(mType){
        case SplashScene:
            this.mSplashScene = new SplashScene(this.mActivity);
            break;


        case LoadingScene:
            mLoadingScene = new LoadingScene(mActivity);
            break;

        case GameModeScene:
            mGameModeScene=new GameModeScene(this.mActivity);
            break;

        case PlayModeScene:
            mPlayModeScene=new PlayModeScene(this.mActivity);
            break;

        case GameScene:
            break;

            default:
        }
    }
```

Constructor of each class is loading the resources.

---

Here is how m getiing current Scene Instance

**SceneController.getScene()**
    public Scene getScene(SceneType mType){

```
        switch(mType){
        case SplashScene:
            this.mCurrentScene = mSplashScene;
            break;


        case LoadingScene:
            this.mCurrentScene = mLoadingScene;
            break;

        case GameModeScene:
            this.mCurrentScene = mGameModeScene;
            break;

        case PlayModeScene:
            this.mCurrentScene = mPlayModeScene;
            break;

            default:
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene class, there's a reset() method, which is what I assume you're referring to when you say

> I tried pGameModeSceneto.reset(); but it won't work.

All that method does is the following:

```
@Override
public void reset() {
    super.reset();

    this.clearChildScene();
}
```

Your scenes (i assume) are extending Scene.  So when you call reset() on them, all you're doing is initializing the parent-level information and up-the-tree from there via the super.reset() call.  (Scene extends Entity.)  None of the private fields that you create and set in your scene would be affected by this.  To get the behavior you want, override the reset() method in your individual scene classes.  Make sure to call super.reset() at the start of them and add initializing information, i.e., whatever your "empty" scene should look like.  Something like this:

```
@Override
public void reset() {
    super.reset();
    myLocalInt = 0; 
    myLocalFancyPantsObject = null;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've noticed @jmr499485 is saying essentially the same thing (and saying it before me).  You should award him the check.  Unless we're both misunderstanding you, our answers to the question of "the variables aren't resetting" are "why would they?"

Comment: Yeahh i did the same thing finally. I understood that it's a basics of java that variables won't reset until you recreate the instance of class or reset them manually;  Thanks to both of you

Comment: It's a feature, not a bug. :)  If you want to award one of those green checkmarks, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: ur Overriding of reset method makes perfect sense and i did the same. Ty :)

Comment: @CamFred - thanks - it's all good. glad the OP got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

what you have said makes perfectly good sense given what you have told us.

You probably want to add a `reset()` method of some kind to your Scene(s) and call that when you switch to a different scene - or when you leave a particular scene.

But ... if they are your variables in your class, then that built in `reset()` method can't reset your variables.

Add a method like `resetSceneVars()` and reinitialize anything that needs to be the same as it was when you created the scene. As long as you maintain a reference to the scene, those variables will keep their latest values.